# how to extract a string/char from a formatted file input using fscanf in C?

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to extract an operator from the input file using fscanf, operator being (+,-,*,/) which is located in this line "(C = (A[i] OP B[i]) + C) << 3;". How can i approach this?

```
FILE *file = fopen("project2Input.txt", "r");
if (file == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file");
    return 1;
}
int k, N;
char op[3];
fscanf(file, "long myFunction(long A[], long B[], int k, int N) {");
fscanf(file, "long C;");
fscanf(file, "for (int i = %d; i < %d; i++){", &k, &N);
fscanf(file, "(C = (A[i] %2[-+*/] B[i]) + C) << 3;", op);
op[2] = '\0';
fscanf(file, "} return C;}");
fclose(file);
printf("op: %s\n", op);

//input file (project2Input.txt)
long myFunction(long A[], long B[], int k, int N) {
    long C;
    for (int i = k; i < N; i++){
        (C = (A[i] - B[i]) + C) << 3;
    }
    return C;
}
```

Comment: To all questions of the form "how do I ... with scanf?", the answer is generally, "don't".  scanf is not a useful tool.  It seems appealing, but there are better ways to do it that will cause less confusion and provide greater learning.

Comment: `perror("project2Input.txt");` provides a much more useful error message.  Even better is `const char *path = ... ; if( (file=fopen(path, mode)) == NULL ) {perror(path); ...`

Comment: If you're going to use `*scanf`, get in the habit of always checking the return value.  Every single time.  If you ignore the value returned by any of the functions in the `scanf` familyl, you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: @Zayed Aldhaheri "How can i approach this?" --> What should happen if the input does not match the expected form?  (i.e. `scanf()` fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator string is one character long, so `%2[-+*/]` should be `%1[-+*/]` and `char op[3];` can be changed to `char op[2] = "";` to reduce its size and initialize it.

`%d` will not match the `'k'` and `'N'` characters in the `for` loop. Maybe use `%c` to match them and change `int k, N;` to `char k, N;`.

Optional white-space should be allowed between all C tokens. You can use a white-space character in the scanf format string wherever optional white-space is allowed.

There needs to be mandatory white-space matching between some C tokens such as between `long` and `myFunction`, otherwise `longMyfunction` would be matched. C interprets the *space*, *newline*, *form-feed*, *horizontal tab*, and *vertical tab* characters as white-space. It also converts comments to white-space, but let us ignore the possibility of comments in the **project2Input.txt** file as it is tricky to deal with!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MWS "%*[ \f\n\t\v]" /* match mandatory white-space */

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = fopen("project2Input.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    char op[2] = "";
    char k, N;
    fscanf(file, " long" MWS "myFunction ( long" MWS "A [ ] , long" MWS
                 "B [ ] , int" MWS "k , int" MWS "N ) {");
    fscanf(file, " long" MWS "C ;");
    fscanf(file, " for ( int" MWS "i = %c ; i < %c ; i ++ ) {", &k, &N);
    fscanf(file, " ( C = ( A [ i ] %1[-+*/] B [ i ] ) + C ) << 3 ;", op);
    fscanf(file, " } return" MWS "C ; }");
    fclose(file);
    printf("op: %s\n", op);
}
```